# SharePoint 2013 Upgrade to SharePoint 2016 - Missing Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, office-online-server

I moved a SharePoint 2013 content db to SharePoint 2016 environment (SQL 2016) and ran test-spcontentdatabase.  The following results were returned:

Category        : MissingWebPart
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : WebPart class [e6002ce8-69ee-168a-8f7c-a1d98d51da29] (class [Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.ExcelWebRenderer] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is 
                  referenced [14] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part.
Remedy          : One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.
Locations       :

Category        : MissingWebPart
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : WebPart class [b4bd2bdf-cf0c-ffce-ecb1-ae7c4882e17a] (class [Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.ExcelWebRenderer] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is 
                  referenced [226] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part.
Remedy          : One or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.
Locations       :

Is this because I need to install an Office Online Server farm for SharePoint 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as we are getting **UpgradeBlocking : False**  this will not harm anything in the target environment, in migration project these are generic errors during content DB migration we may see - some errors even we may troubleshoot by cleaning up using the PowerShell script provided by the Microsoft. In the below articles details steps are mentioned.

When it comes to Office Online Server setup - it is recommended to have the office online server connected in the farm, however, we can set up and configure the office online server post migration also.

You may refer the below article, for the tips and tricks in in SharePoint content DB migration project :

[SharePoint Migration: Basic tips and tricks in migration project](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/basic-tips-and-tricks-in-sharepoint-migration-project/)

Answer (score 0):

The Test-SPcontentdatabase is telling you that some web parts are missing, however the UpgradeBlocking is false, which means that this issue won't block your upgrade.

You need to install all of your solutions that you have deployed in your SharePoint 2013 farm are installed in your SharePoint 2016 farm.